# EDIT --Python3 Beautifulsoup grabing elements from website

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract the "game name" in these links from Metacritc this is how far I've gotten with this code:

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

url = "http://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/score/metascore/year/pc/filtered?sort=desc&year_selected=2018"
req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

web_byte = urlopen(req).read()

webpage = web_byte.decode('utf-8')

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'lxml')

game_name = html_soup.find_all("div", class_="product_item product_title")

print(game_name)
```

this prints (along with all the others that I want

```
<div class="product_item product_title">
    <a href="/game/pc/into-the-breach">
                        Into the Breach
                                        </a>
    </div>,

and so on ....
```

I want to know how to target just one of them and just the name (trying to make variables that are the strings out of them)

also How would I target the 2nd and 3rd ones (I tried [1] and [2] but it ends up in error (see below)...maybe I'm doing something wrong?)

when I try this method (.find()):

```
game_name = html_soup.find("div", class_="product_item product_title").text
```

I get the text but looks like it's not perfect (spaces and line breaks)

```
            Into the Breach
```

[edit] I used strip() and it cleaned up the text

but when I try

```
game_name = html_soup.find("div", class_="product_item product_title")[1].text
```

i get this error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-bd2752bc8407> in <module>()
      7 html_soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'lxml')
      8 
----> 9 game_name = html_soup.find("div", class_={"product_item product_title"})[1].text
     10 
     11 print(game_name)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bs4/element.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1009         """tag[key] returns the value of the 'key' attribute for the tag,
   1010         and throws an exception if it's not there."""
-> 1011         return self.attrs[key]
   1012 
   1013     def __iter__(self):

KeyError: 1
```

Please help, I am very new to this stuff

Answer (score 0):

You want to use find_all() not find().

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all

> The find_all() method looks through a tag’s descendants and retrieves
>   all descendants that match your filters.

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find

> The only difference is that find_all() returns a list containing the
>   single result, and find() just returns the result.

```
game_name = html_soup.find_all("div", class_="product_item product_title")[1].text.strip()
```

Outputs:

```
Pillars of Eternity II: Deadfire
```